# Trying to understand p-queue concurrency

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to use p-queue under nodejs to spin up a bunch of API calls; however, I don't want them to get to out of control and bring down the server. So the through was that I would set the concurrency to only run a few at a time. But it didn't work out that way and I'm trying to understand why.

If there is no concurrency restriction my counter passes to my function as expected.

```
// No concurrency
import PQueue from 'p-queue';
console.time('bunch-of-stuff');

var queue = new PQueue();

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        queue.add(() => httpProcess(i));
    }

console.timeEnd('bunch-of-stuff');

function httpProcess(pageNumber) {  

    console.log('Done: ' + pageNumber);
}

Output:
1
Done: 1
2
Done: 2
3
Done: 3
4
Done: 4
5
Done: 5
bunch-of-stuff: 9.385ms
```

If I set a limiting concurrency value the number of sessions set by the concurrency work perfectly; however, all remaining receive the value of the counter after the count has finished.

```
// Set concurrency to 1
import PQueue from 'p-queue';
console.time('bunch-of-stuff');

var queue = new PQueue({concurrency: 2});

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        queue.add(() => httpProcess(i));
    }

console.timeEnd('bunch-of-stuff');

function httpProcess(pageNumber) {  

    console.log('Done: ' + pageNumber);
}

Output:
1
Done: 1
2
Done: 2
3
4
5
bunch-of-stuff: 10.596ms
Done: 6
Done: 6
Done: 6
```

Help. Any thoughts would be appreciated. I'm just trying to understand why I loose my count on any number over and beyond the concurrency value.

Comment: `var i` vs. `let i`, but either way those threads could be evaluated after your loop finishes, as shown above. In that case, you're still grabbing the value of `i` when they are executed, but the loop has already finished (with the result `i=6`).

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30479554/10317684) explains it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how closures work in Javascript, nothing to do with specific library. The issue comes from how `i` is passed to the inner callback

```
() => httpProcess(i)
```

Note that the only way to have `i` there is the closure. Closure is implemented as an extra object passed to the function with *fields* of specific names and values. In your case there's only one field, `i`.

Now comes the problem. The closure is initialized in the scope of outer function but there's your loop. The loop body **alters** the value of the `i` in the closure object and since it's always the very same object, effectively the value of `i` is shared between all instances of the inner callback.

```
// closure is initialized here
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    // the very same closure object is passed to the callback
    queue.add(() => httpProcess(i));
}
```

There are couple of solutions.

First, you can add an extra function **inside the loop** so that the closure is initialized for each loop iteration:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        // closure is created here
        // and since we are already inside a loop
        // we have an extra closure in each loop iteration
        console.log(i);
        queue.add(() => httpProcess(i));
    })(i);
}
```

Another possible solution is to replace `var` by `let` - it effectively does the same as above as `let` is just a sugar for introducing an extra function scope:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    queue.add(() => httpProcess(i));
}
```

The latter is of course shorter, cleaner and I believe it should be favored over the former.

However, it's worth of realizing that the latter is just a syntactic sugar for the former.